# Array Dinâmico - Android

Tags: android, array

Como criar um array dinâmico desse forma:

```
//Apenas um exemplo abaixo:

String valor0 = "1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;0";
String valor1 = "1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;0";
String valor2 = "1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;0";

//Um array dentro de outro array, porém sem definir seu tamanho
String[][] valor = {};

//E então definir os valores do segundo [] com split também
valor[0][] = valor0.split(";");
valor[1][] = valor1.split(";");
valor[2][] = valor2.split(";");
```

Assim ele criaria as chaves e após criar, definir os valores do outro array dentro de cada chave com o split. O tamanho deve ser com o split, pois este será dinâmico, irá mudar constantemente. Em casos de ser apenas um array normal, sei que o split o povoa de forma dinâmica sem precisar definir o tamanho, mas gostaria de fazer o mesmo com um array bidimensional.

O exemplo não funciona, lógico, é somente para mostrar.

O array ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=10)
      0 => string '1' (length=1)
      1 => string '2' (length=1)
      2 => string '3' (length=1)
      3 => string '4' (length=1)
      4 => string '5' (length=1)
      5 => string '6' (length=1)
      6 => string '7' (length=1)
      7 => string '8' (length=1)
      8 => string '9' (length=1)
      9 => string '0' (length=1)
  1 => 
    array (size=10)
      0 => string '1' (length=1)
      1 => string '2' (length=1)
      2 => string '3' (length=1)
      3 => string '4' (length=1)
      4 => string '5' (length=1)
      5 => string '6' (length=1)
      6 => string '7' (length=1)
      7 => string '8' (length=1)
      8 => string '9' (length=1)
      9 => string '0' (length=1)
  2 => 
    array (size=10)
      0 => string '1' (length=1)
      1 => string '2' (length=1)
      2 => string '3' (length=1)
      3 => string '4' (length=1)
      4 => string '5' (length=1)
      5 => string '6' (length=1)
      6 => string '7' (length=1)
      7 => string '8' (length=1)
      8 => string '9' (length=1)
      9 => string '0' (length=1)
```

Fiz esse exemplo em php

Comment: Parece me que está à procura de `ArrayList<String[]>` e não `String[][]`

Comment: @Isac pior que eu não sei na verdade kkkkk, poderia fazer um exemplo :3

Comment: @WotonSampaio você quer array de inteiros ou de string?

Comment: @Felipe de Strings

Comment: @Felipe foi mal, é pq no php acabei deixando como int, já corrigi aqui kkk

Comment: Tranquilo é que se fosse inteiro teria um trabalhinho pra converter, antes de jogar no vetor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se precisa que o array seja dinâmico utilize uma implementação de [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html), como por exemplo um [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

De acordo com o exemplo que deu apenas as linhas necessitariam de ser dinamicas, e nesse caso poderia definir o array como:

```
ArrayList<String[]> valor
```

Isto permite-lhe adicionar quantos array de `String`s quiser. Os próprios arrays adicionados não tem de ser do mesmo tamanho e por isso podem apanhar o tamanho que vem do `split`. A adição passa a ser feita com o método [`add`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add-E-) ao invés de pelo índice.

Exemplo:

```
String valor0 = "1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;0";
String valor1 = "1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;0";
String valor2 = "1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;0";

ArrayList<String[]> valor = new ArrayList<>();

valor.add(valor0.split(";")); //adiciona cada linha com add
valor.add(valor1.split(";"));
valor.add(valor2.split(";"));
```

Agora para utilizar basta dois `for` um para as linhas e outro para as colunas:

```
for (String[] linha : valor){ //percorrer cada linha
    for (String item : linha){ //percorrer cada item/coluna na linha
        System.out.print(item + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

[Veja este exemplo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/fOeOQc)

Vale lembrar que com um `ArrayList` para aceder a uma posição tem de utilizar o método `get`. Logo se quiser mais tarde aceder ao segundo valor da primeira linha teria que fazer:

```
String segundoPrimeiraLinha = valor.get(0)[1];
//------------------------------------^
```

Onde num `String[][]` faria:

```
String segundoPrimeiraLinha = valor[0][1];
```

Comment: Cara, eu te amo kkkkkkkk

Comment: @WotonSampaio Estamos cá para ajudar :)

Answer (score 1):

Só para mostrar que isso é possível com um array multidimensional, tal como o AP solicita.

```
String valor0 = "1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;0";
String valor1 = "1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;0";
String valor2 = "1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;0";

String[][] valor = new String[3][];

valor[0] = valor0.split(";");
valor[1] = valor1.split(";");
valor[2] = valor2.split(";");

for(String[] linha : valor) {           
    for (String item : linha) {     
        System.out.print(item + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Veja no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/E2aDvJ).

Comment: E se caso eu não tivesse o tamanho do array principal, sendo realmente [][], também seria possível?

Comment: Depende da forma como tem os dados guardados. No entanto qualquer que seja a forma você saberá, ou poderá sempre saber, o número de linhas(dimensão do "array principal")

Comment: O que é aquela `String chave = "0,1,2";`?

Comment: Seriam as chaves, mas na vdd elas não importam, vou até tirar aqui

Comment: É como se eu definisse o tamanho do array a partir desse tamanho, e então colocasse os dados no outro array, ex:  `array = chave.split(",")` Aí o array principal passaria a ter um tamanho de 3, então agora eu adicionaria os valores no outro array `array[1][] = valor0.split(";");`

Comment: Foi só uma lógica maluca pra explicar minha duvida

Comment: Então, estou certo quando digo que você sabe sempre o número de linhas?

Comment: Não, pois tipo, os valores vem de um db, e a cada vez que eu adiciono um novo usuário, ele aumenta, aí eu não saberia quantos iriam vir, por isso necessitaria ser dinâmico

Comment: A menos que tivesse outro array que só amontoasse
tudo, então eu criaria esse novo array bidimensional usando o tamanho desse primeiro array

Comment: O melhor seria você fazer outra pergunta com o cenário real porque, se percebi bem, isso deveria ser feito com outro tipo de colecção.

Comment: Acho que não é necessário :/, eu testei aqui com o arraylist e funcionou bem, percebi que você se interessou pelo assunto kkkkk, mas basicamente a dúvida era criar um array bidimensional sem saber o seu tamanho, nem do principal nem do array que fica dentro de cada chave, assim o inserindo de forma dinâmica utilizando o split()

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando List você consegue criá-las dinamicamente segue o **código**:

```
List<List<String>> valor = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
valor.add(Arrays.asList(valor0.split(";"));
valor.add(Arrays.asList(valor1.split(";"));
valor.add(Arrays.asList(valor2.split(";"));
```

Comment: Cara, seu exemplo da um exeption nas 3 linha onde são adicionados os valores :3

Comment: Adicionou as bibliotecas?

Comment: Sim, eu testei o ideone.com, o erro ao adicionar era na vdd pq faltou fechar os parenteses, fica assim: `valor.add(Arrays.asList(valor0.split(";")));` , porem mesmo assim deu outra exception : `Main.java:18: error: incompatible types: ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> cannot be converted to List<List<String>>`

Comment: Dá uma olhada : https://ideone.com/VwTqoA

Comment: Acho que o certo seria assim: `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> valor = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        valor.add((ArrayList<String>) Arrays.asList(valor0.split(";")));
        valor.add((ArrayList<String>) Arrays.asList(valor1.split(";")));
        valor.add((ArrayList<String>) Arrays.asList(valor2.split(";")));`

Comment: Nao é certeza, porém só assim o android studio parou de mostrar como erro