# Array x ArrayList

Tags: android, array

Ontem fiz uma [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/289201/array-din%C3%A2mico-android) sobre como utilizar um **Array Bidimensional** de forma dinâmica, então acabei recebendo uma resposta para usar um **ArrayList**, e este serviu perfeitamente para meu caso, porem, a partir disso me gerou a duvida, quando devo utilizar um ou outro?

Mesmo em casos simples, onde não seria necessário a modificação dos dados, eu percebi que o **ArrayList** me serviu tão bem quanto um **Array** normal, então gostaria de saber, quando é mais necessário ou certo utilizar um **Array** do que um **ArrayList**?

Comment: Se precisa armazenar uma lista de algum tipo primitivo, somente vai conseguir com arrays, pois com ArrayList você não consegue criar com tipos primitivos, somente com wrappers. Array é melhor para quando você tem controle sobre a quantidade de dados a ser armazenado, e sabe que ele não sofrerá alterações, pois uma vez criado, não há como expandir ou reduzir, e ja com arraylist, apesar de ser possivel definir tamanho inicial, ela é expansivel sem necessidade de sua intervencao.

Comment: Ah, do ponto de vista performatico, arrays são mais rapidos que Collections, mas somente para casos em que a criacao, leitura e troca de dados seja intensa. Para a grande maioria dos casos, nem é possivel notar essa diferença.